# Turn off Lower Power Mode on iPod Touch

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

How do I turn off Low Power Mode if my iPod Touch with iOS 9.3.5 does not have a Turn Low Power Mode On/Off button or slide bar?

Comment: go to settings/battery...

Answer (score 3):

Go into Settings > Battery > Turn Off Low Power Mode. If that doesn't work ask Siri to turn off Low Power Mode for you.